# What is the right logic for a function that compares one value against all elements of an array?

Tags: c, crud

I am writing a CRUD program in C and at one point the user is asked to input an employee's code, which was previously stored in an array called "codes" in an employee registration section of the program, in order to register an employee's vehicle. The program should only continue if the user input is identical to an element of the codes array. Both user input and elements of the array are properly formatted, so there should be no differences other than the actual code.

---

I debugged by trying the value 1234 for the employee's code, which is successfully stored in the codes array, then I tried registering a vehicle by typing 1234, but the function I wrote that does the checking always return 0, so I'm thinking there is a flaw in the logic.

Variables:

```
char codes[100][256];
char owner[256];
```

**Function to check if user input is indeed in any element of the array codes, returns 1 if it finds a match, or 0 at the end.**

```
int checkOwner(char t_code[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < indice; ++i)
    {
        if(!strcmp(t_code, codes[i])) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Input processing:**

```
            do {
                printf("Type owner's code: ");
                fgets(owner, sizeof(owner), stdin);
                owner[strcspn(owner, "\n")] = '\0';
                if(!checkOwner(owner))
                    printf("No employee with that code, try again.\n");
            } while(!checkOwner(owner));
```

Comment: Research `memcmp()` to compare all of an array, yet it looks like you still only want part of the array (a _string_).  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Where's your debug printing?  Have you printed what's in `owner`?  Use `printf("Owner: [%s]\n", owner);` immediately before the `if`.  Have you checked the values in `indice` and `codes` — probably in the `checkOwner()` function?  You could print `t_code` in the function too.  Yes, it'll be noisy, but it will probably tell you what's going wrong.  For example, did your previous test code not remove the newlines, and does the `codes` array contain newlines?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes I tested all of those things and if I strcmp specifically codes[0] (in the case I register a single employee) and t_code, it returns 0, which means they are identical. It must be something in the logic, I think.

Comment: What is the nature of a `code`? If they are numerical, you could fit every possible code, one pointer to a data structure, in memory, you could have a very easy `O(1)` lookup instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: Well, it should be easy enough to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same idea by a different name.  It only needs 2 or 3 codes in the codes array.  And you can show the code working one way and not working the other in the MCVE test program.  With that in the question, your problem will probably be resolved very quickly.  As it is, we only have fragments, and what we provide as infrastructure won't replicate your bug.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < indice; ++i)` Now, what is `indice` ? A global?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "logic flaw" stands in the for statement:

```
for (int i = 0; i < indice; ++i)
```

From the logic I see you want to go through all the codes you actually registered. However, at each iteration you would like to go to the next "line", but you only update `i` by one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < indice; i+=256)
```

should solve the problem hopefully, though I think at this point the condition `i < indice` will cause problems (you could then use a second variable to count the "line number")

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < indice; i+=256, ++j)
```

I would also explicitly say:

```
if(strcmp(t_code, codes[i]) == 0)
```

Comment: `i+=256`, no?..

Comment: @LeeTaylor totally right, I misspelled..

Comment: You are super right that it was in the for statement! However, all I had to do was change indice (which is a super useless variable I will remove later), to MAX which is the actual number of elements I defined to my 2d array codes!